# How to merge rows by index value from two different dataframe using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new in Python Pandas. I have two dataframe which contain some rows and column but data are not same on both the dataframe. I need to merge both the dataframe with same index value and fill the data from second dataframe in first dataframe in missing place

DF1

[image]

DF2

[image]

Output_DF

[image]

```
Output_DF = pd.concat([DF1, DF2])
```

The expected output should be like Output_DF file all the row values from DF2 will be merged with DF1 index and fill the missing place of the same index.

Answer (score 0):

After setting your index, you can just `fillna`

```
DF1=DF1.set_index('index')
DF2=DF2.set_index('index')

Output_DF=DF1.fillna(DF2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try update dataframe in this scenario.

```
enter code here
update1_df.set_index('Index',inplace=True)   
update2_df.set_index('Index',inplace=True)   
update1_df.update(update2_df) 
update1_df
```